# Good way to check all checkboxes in Laravel-blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

Is there any good way to put "All-cheked" button on Blade PHP?
I've tried to control it by JavaScript. However, Each checkbox name is different.
Even I am aware this way seems not a good method.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      function AllChecked(){
        var all = document.form.all.checked;
        for (var i=0; i<document.form.test.length; i++){
          document.form.test[i].checked = all;
        }
      }

      function　DisChecked(){
        var checks = document.form.test;
        var checksCount = 0;
        for (var i=0; i<checks.length; i++){
          if(checks[i].checked == false){
            document.form.all.checked = false;
          }else{
            checksCount += 1;
            if(checksCount == checks.length){
              document.form.all.checked = true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
</script>
```

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){{$i}}
<div>
{{date('m-d',strtotime($i." day"))}}
<input type="checkbox" name="available_date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{{$i}} day")) ?>">
<button onClick="AllChecked();">ALL Checked </button>
@for ($j = 0; $j < 25; $j++)
<input type="checkbox" name="{{date('Y-m-d',strtotime($i." day"))}}" value="{{$j}}">{{ $j }}:00
@endfor
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Actually you can't control dynamic users behavior by PHP, because PHP works only on server, so all such things are managing by javascript (if I understood you correctly)
2. Not 100% sure, but seems you don't need both checkbox and button for `All Checked`
3. In javascript you can select all checkboxes using a class (will show example with jquery for simplicity)

```
// html
<input type="checkbox" class="all_checked" name="available_date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{{$i}} day")) ?>">
@for ($j = 0; $j < 25; $j++)
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="{{date('Y-m-d',strtotime($i." day"))}}" value="{{$j}}">{{ $j }}:00
@endfor
```

```
// js
$('.all_checked').on('click', function () {
    const allCheckedCheckbox = $(this);
    $('.checkbox').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', allCheckedCheckbox.prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

Comment: I modified as it  but it doesn't seem to work...```@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){{$i}}
<div>
{{date('m/d :',strtotime($i." day"))}}
<input type="checkbox" class="all_checked"  name="available_date" value="{{ date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{{$i}} day")) }}">
<button onClick ="AllChecked()" >ALL Checked</button>
@for ($j = 0; $j < 25; $j++)
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="{{date('Y-m-d',strtotime($i." day"))}}" value="{{$j}}">{{ $j }}:00
@endfor
</div>```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jquery.

Simply add a common class to each of the checkboxes

ex :- class="checkbox"

And write a js function

```
  function AllChecked(){
     $('.checkbox').attr("checked");
  }
```